# Rounding a number to next highest greatest place

Tags: android

I have a list, and there I get the highest integer.

Examples:

```
int 6257 -> I want to round it to 10'000
int 480 -> I want to round it to 1000
int 48 -> I want to round it to 100
int 3 -> I want tot round it to 10
```

I have tried it like Math.round(value/1000)*1000 but it's not what I want. And I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: One approach would be to convert the integer to a string, count the number of characters (call it *n*), and build a new string "1" followed by *n* zeroes.

Comment: By the way you haven't specified what you want to happen with zero or negative numbers, so if those are possible inputs, you may not get a correct or complete answer.

Comment: just a tip for you @JonnyDough, but this is not an android question, you should have just flagged this as Java/kotlin instead.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
int roundToNearestPowerOfTen(int number) {
    int exponent = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(number));
    return (int) Math.pow(10, exponent);
}
```

It takes the log base 10 of the number, rounds up the fraction, and returns 10 to that power.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer when it's possible for me.